# Handling properties of a class that are assigned using an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, asynchronous

In a scenario where I have a class `ShopManager` with a property `_itemCategories` whose value is going to be set to the return value of an asynchronous function, since I couldn't use `async/await` inside the class' constructor, I declared an `init` async function which would be called from the outside and would set its value.

However, the initial value of `_itemCategories`, before `init` is called, would be either `null` or `undefined`. This makes me have to check if an instance of `ShopManager`'s `itemCategories` is present every single time I use it anywhere on my application, which isn't ideal.

```js
import type { Application } from '../application';

export class ShopManager {
    private readonly _application: Application;
    private _itemCategories: string[] | null = null;

    public get itemCategories() {
        return this._itemCategories;
    }
    
    public constructor(application: Application) {
        this._application = application;
    }

    public async init() {
        this._itemCategories = await this._getItemCategories();
    }

    private async _getItemCategories(): Promise<string[]> {
        const categories = await this._application.storage.itemCategory.findMany();
        return categories.map((category) => category.name);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way to set properties of classes based on the return of asynchronous functions, or if I can somehow make TypeScript infer that `itemCategories` is present after calling `init` (extremely unlikely I believe).

Comment: `private _itemCategories!: string[];`

Comment: @Konrad I considered that... But it feels dirty

Comment: [Don't asynchronously initialise the instance in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572) (or right after construction) - instead, load the data *before* creating the manager instance.

Comment: Love that @Bergi, thank you.